# What should be the PTR for a mail server which is also a web server?

Tags: networking, dns

I have the following A records for a server @ IP address `1.2.3.4`:

```
Name: example.com.
Name: *.example.com.
Name: example.net.
```

My server FQDN is `server1.example.com`.

Currently, emails are send out with the envelope sender as no-reply@`$SERVER_NAME` where the `$SERVER_NAME` is `example.com` most of the time. Under this scenario, should the domain name in PTR be `example.com`?

If I change the `$SERVER_NAME` to `mail.example.com`, do I have to add this name to both A and PTR records? What should be the strategy for PTR for a mail server which is also a web server that uses wildcard subdomains?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** It's entirely allowable for one IP to have multiple PTR records, but if you prefer to stick with one, go with `mail.example.com`.

**Long version**:

As per the DNS reverse lookup specs, it's perfectly okay to have multiple PTR records for one IP. It's not usually done, but the [spec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup#Multiple_pointer_records) doesn't forbid it.

That *said*, the reason it's not usually done is because there's rarely a reason for it. As an example, in the case you cite there's really no reason why a webserver's reverse lookup should match all or even any of the hostnames of the sites it serves.

SMTP, on the other hand, has been gradually tightening up its concept of security over the past few decades due to massive amounts of spam, and most spam filters nowadays at the very least attach a nontrivial "weight" to the flag of "Reverse lookup does not match forward lookup" because it implies that the sending server may not be who it claims to be. More strictly configured filters may even refuse to accept mail outright from a server whose forward and reverse lookups don't match.

By having both the forward A record and the reverse PTR record match the name the mail server uses to identify itself during the HELO/EHLO handshake you demonstrate that the person who configured the server has the administrative ability to change the DNS entries for that server as well, making it more likely to be a legitimate server -- or at least, more likely to be *accountable*.

**ETA** Another thing that would be wise to do if you have control over your DNS settings is to add a SPF ([Sender Policy Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework)) record that positively identifies your server by IP and hostname as being authorized to send mail from your domain. Sites like the [SPF Wizard](http://www.spfwizard.net/) can help you construct what said record would need to look like.

Comment: With the added detail that the name referenced in the MX record for example.com is the important one here.  The  A and PTR records for that name/IP should match.  If mail.example.com is in the MX record for example.com, then this is correct.

Comment: @milli Not necessarily. He's talking about an *outgoing* mail server; this is not always the same as the *incoming* mail server, and only the latter would be listed in the MX records.

Comment: Most MTAs check SPF records on senders, so yes, it does matter in both directions.

Comment: SPF records, yes. MX records, not necessarily. Again, they're not intrinsically the same thing even though most SPF records contain a `mx` stanza.

Comment: @milli That said, good point about SPF, answer amended to include.

Comment: OP says his server hostname is `server1.example.com` which is different from the envelope sender header `mail.example.com`. Won't the HELO/EHLO still be `server1.example.com`? And if A record already has a `*.example.com`, does he need to add anything there?

Comment: @questionOverflow That depends. If his SMTP software is set to introduce itself with its hostname, it'll HELO as `server1.example.com`; if it's set to identify as `mail.example.com` then it'll HELO as `mail.example.com`. For instance, in Postfix this is determined by the `mailname` configuration setting in `main.cf`.

Comment: @QuestionOverflow Using a wildcard A record would help in the forward lookup, but be of no use at all during the reverse check.

Comment: Yes, he would need a PTR for the reverse check. But does the domain in the forward lookup need to match the reverse exactly? i.e. is matching `example.com` sufficient enough for the mail to pass SPAM check using FCrDNS or does the `mail/server1.example.com` need to be added to the A record?

Comment: @QuestionOverflow You appear to misunderstand how a wildcard A record works. If your zone information says that (for instance) `*.example.com` points to 1.2.3.4, a lookup of `mail.example.com`  will return 1.2.3.4 as will a lookup of `server1.example.com` as will a lookup of `supercalifragulisticespiallidocious.example.com`. As far as the asker is concerned, there is *no* difference between an answer derived from a wildcard and an answer with a specific record.

Comment: Quoting from the OP `mail.example.com, do I have to add this name to both A and PTR records`. That is also part of what the OP is trying to find out right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17071/discussion-between-shadur-and-question-overflow).

Comment: Sorry, I have problem logging in to chat every time I try to use it. Would prefer to use the comment. Thanks.

Comment: @questionoverflow Judging by the original question, the OP doesn't understand what they're asking terribly well either, which is why I attempted to explain what's actually going on and went from there. You, on the other hand, are starting to badly derail the discussion by adding hypotheticals that the OP didn't ask about and may not even be in play, and *I have better things to do with my time* than try educating **two** people, one of whom seems to be acting deliberately obtuse.

Answer (score 0):

The machine should have a name. If the machine's name is `mail.example.com`, then the PTR record should be to `mail.example.com`.